# Need to remove duplicates by ID

Tags: mysql

I've got a query that successfully analyzes my table for duplicates that match 100% of the fields in question and returns a count of duplicates.  Now I need to write a query that returns the record ID values so that I can delete them.  Here's my initial query:

```
SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(*) AS dupecount
FROM artist_reports
GROUP BY contemporary, traditional, country, folk, functional, decorative, abstract, representational, figurative, price_range_low,
  price_range_high, best_selling_range_low, best_selling_range_high, average_sales_other_shows, total_sales_this_event, average_exhibitor_quality, financial_fairness, patrons_art_savvy, demographics, buying_energy,
  advertising, venue_environment, show_layout, organization, director_support, staff_support, logistical_ease, load_in_out, parking_ease, artist_amenities,
  awards_judging, security_efficiency, weather, event_year, critique, artist_reports.status, public_email, artist_reports.email, would_you_return, fairs_per_year, CompanyID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

In theory, I have a link to another page that passes the CompanyID which would then delete the duplicates. However, I tried this and it only returns one record:

```
SELECT arid FROM artist_reports WHERE arid IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT arid
      FROM artist_reports
      WHERE CompanyID = 12345
      GROUP BY contemporary, traditional, country, folk, functional, decorative, abstract, representational, figurative, price_range_low,
        price_range_high, best_selling_range_low, best_selling_range_high, average_sales_other_shows, total_sales_this_event, average_exhibitor_quality, financial_fairness, patrons_art_savvy, demographics, buying_energy,
        advertising, venue_environment, show_layout, organization, director_support, staff_support, logistical_ease, load_in_out, parking_ease, artist_amenities,
        awards_judging, security_efficiency, weather, event_year, critique, artist_reports.status, public_email, artist_reports.email, would_you_return, fairs_per_year, CompanyID
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS a )
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but ideally I'd like to get a recordset of unique ID values for a report (*arid*) and then iterate through those to delete the newest ones, leaving the original intact.

Comment: when you filter by `CompanyID=12345` you lose some duplicates. for example, suppose you have two records with different CompanyID and the same value for other fields, in the first query these rows appears but in the  second query, you have just one row. i hope I am clear?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean -- however, I've got the initial query set up to group by CompanyID (e.g., 5 duplicates for CompanyID 12345, 3 duplicates for CompanyID 67890).  The user then clicks on the CompanyID they'd like to clear and then the next query needs to find duplicates only for that specific CompanyID.

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: That's arid, the one that I'm trying to retrieve in my second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle you could use window functions, but here you need to cheat a bit.

I assume that you probably want to remove duplicates by `arid`. To get all ids using your query, try to add `GROUP_CONCAT` to it:

```
SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(*) AS dupecount,   
      GROUP_CONCAT(arid) AS all_duplicates_ids
FROM artist_reports
GROUP BY contemporary, traditional, country, folk, functional, decorative, abstract, representational, figurative, price_range_low,
  price_range_high, best_selling_range_low, best_selling_range_high, average_sales_other_shows, total_sales_this_event, average_exhibitor_quality, financial_fairness, patrons_art_savvy, demographics, buying_energy,
  advertising, venue_environment, show_layout, organization, director_support, staff_support, logistical_ease, load_in_out, parking_ease, artist_amenities,
  awards_judging, security_efficiency, weather, event_year, critique, artist_reports.status, public_email, artist_reports.email, would_you_return, fairs_per_year, CompanyID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now you will have something like that in result (assuming 5 duplicates):

```
CompanyID|dupecount|all_duplicates_ids
---------------------------------------
12345    |      5  | '2,5,8,9, 12'
```

You don't want to remove all 5 records, just 4 of them, so you can trim this string, by replacing `GROUP_CONCAT` part with:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    CONCAT(
      GROUP_CONCAT(arid),
      ','),
    ',', 1) AS all_duplicates_without_one
```

Now you have coma-separated string with ids. You can use it in your delete query in `where` clause - I suggest using `FIND_IN_SET` function to check if `arid` is in coma-separated string:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

Consider this query to get the row that you want to reserve: (I assumed that the you want to keep the row with minimum arid)

```
 SELECT min(arid) as Original_ID
 ,
 contemporary, traditional, country, folk, functional, decorative, abstract, representational, figurative, price_range_low,
   price_range_high, best_selling_range_low, best_selling_range_high,   average_sales_other_shows, total_sales_this_event, average_exhibitor_quality,       financial_fairness, patrons_art_savvy, demographics, buying_energy,
   advertising, venue_environment, show_layout, organization, director_support, staff_support, logistical_ease, load_in_out, parking_ease, artist_amenities,
   awards_judging, security_efficiency, weather, event_year, critique, artist_reports.status, public_email, artist_reports.email, would_you_return,       fairs_per_year, CompanyID
FROM artist_reports
where CompanyID=12345
GROUP BY contemporary, traditional, country, folk, functional, decorative,   abstract, representational, figurative, price_range_low,
  price_range_high, best_selling_range_low, best_selling_range_high, average_sales_other_shows, total_sales_this_event, average_exhibitor_quality, financial_fairness, patrons_art_savvy, demographics, buying_energy,
 advertising, venue_environment, show_layout, organization, director_support, staff_support, logistical_ease, load_in_out, parking_ease, artist_amenities,
awards_judging, security_efficiency, weather, event_year, critique, artist_reports.status, public_email, artist_reports.email, would_you_return, fairs_per_year, CompanyID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then, Join that query with the original table to get the desired rows:

```
 select a_r.arid from
 artist_reports as a_r
 inner join
 (
 SELECT min(arid) as Original_ID
 ,
 contemporary, traditional, country, folk, functional, decorative, abstract, representational, figurative, price_range_low,
   price_range_high, best_selling_range_low, best_selling_range_high,   average_sales_other_shows, total_sales_this_event, average_exhibitor_quality,       financial_fairness, patrons_art_savvy, demographics, buying_energy,
   advertising, venue_environment, show_layout, organization, director_support, staff_support, logistical_ease, load_in_out, parking_ease, artist_amenities,
   awards_judging, security_efficiency, weather, event_year, critique, artist_reports.status, public_email, artist_reports.email, would_you_return,       fairs_per_year, CompanyID
FROM artist_reports
where CompanyID=12345
GROUP BY contemporary, traditional, country, folk, functional, decorative,   abstract, representational, figurative, price_range_low,
  price_range_high, best_selling_range_low, best_selling_range_high, average_sales_other_shows, total_sales_this_event, average_exhibitor_quality, financial_fairness, patrons_art_savvy, demographics, buying_energy,
 advertising, venue_environment, show_layout, organization, director_support, staff_support, logistical_ease, load_in_out, parking_ease, artist_amenities,
awards_judging, security_efficiency, weather, event_year, critique, artist_reports.status, public_email, artist_reports.email, would_you_return, fairs_per_year, CompanyID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

 ) as duplicates
 on 
 a_r.contemporary=duplicates.contemporary
and
a_r.traditional=duplicates.traditionals
and
.
.
.
where
a_r.arid <> traditional.Original_ID
```

of course you should use delete statement directly in the above query:

```
delete from article_reports as a_r
inner join .......
```